# How to modify Kwicks.js with links for mobile/touch navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, mobile, kwicks

I am trying to build a website with the excellent Wordpress theme Minimatica. Problem is, Minimatica uses a Kwicks.js (jQuery) based slider of image links for its main navigation. These are rollover slides and they don't behave nicely on mobile, since touching any of the slides causes a click-through. I want to tweak it so that on mobile/touch devices, the first touch causes the slider to open, and the second touch actually clicks through. I am not sure how to do this.

A working demo of the theme and the Kwicks panel can be found here:
http://demo.onedesigns.com/minimatica/
Opening it on a mobile device should readily demonstrate the problem.